# Property of light

Tags: visible-light, emergent-properties

Is there any type of light wave which can bend like a thread while travelling? Can this light travel without meeting an obstacle?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Certainly in appropriate (probably completely useless) materials a beam of light will in fact travel on a curve. Without meeting an obstacle or a gravitational field light travels in a line with the speed of light. The influence of gravitation on light is described by general relativity and  one of the most prominent phenomena associated to it is the observation of stars "behind" the sun in 1919 by Arthur Stanley Eddington und Frank Dyson. Note that "travel in a line" is a rather vague statement when talking about the time evolution of fields in 3 spacial dimensions.

Comment: This question is unclear

Comment: Light in an optical fiber can bend just like a thread while traveling (well, the fiber can bend, but don't try to bend it too much or the losses go way up).

Answer (score 3):

Light in a vacuum travels in a straight line.  In fact, in relativity, the definition of a "straight line" is defined by the path light takes.

When you consider light in other mediums, there are a few ways to "bend" light.  Lenses, for example, bend light at the edge between the air and the lens, an effect captured by the concept of refractive indices.

Light also can technically travel around obstacles if it is given an opportunity to behave in some peculiar ways governed by quantum mechanics.  There are cases where light's behavior is better modeled as a wave than as a stream of particles.  In these cases you can see wave behaviors, such as light which reaches a small slit and diffracts like a wave.  When it does so, the effect of this light wave can be measured at locations which cannot draw an unobstructed straight line path to the source.  This isn't quite "bending like a thread," but it is interesting enough to cause a lot of interesting conundrums.